# How can I determine which node mined a specific block in Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, network, p2p

I've amassed a collection of detailed information about various Ethereum nodes, as shown in the example below.

Given this data and a particular block (either by its number or hash), how can I identify which particular node mined a specific block in Ethereum? Are there direct correlations or techniques to determine this, or would I require additional data?

Any pointers or insights would be greatly appreciated!

```json
"00077297427c69ce467f8bb68a3215805f8b7e26b69d91a30445d45732e43330": {
    "Seq": 1667896731784,
    "Signature": "40919aa714421533b93cd107d18f0965e18e255fcd2c427f373ed9fa64227f7329bbd5ad971741f12e0f4bfcb08f6e4dc45a7f36ac2d8f94b704da4d0fe60ff7",
    "secp256k1": "a103ef9804fe30a974a058e2ebd3d72c9365f6dfb7b06208f8cc9d95e0f62836b901",
    "NodeID": "00077297427c69ce467f8bb68a3215805f8b7e26b69d91a30445d45732e43330",
    "URLv4": "enode://ef9804fe30a974a058e2ebd3d72c9365f6dfb7b06208f8cc9d95e0f62836b901534eedc1f8c0b7b56f08b463b77ba7836d4efd6e2952a8c75d4d08b6dcaae9d9@89.163.140.74:30303",
    "VersionId": "\"v4\"",
    "Ip": "89.163.140.74",
    "Ip6": "",
    "Tcp": "30303",
    "Tcp6": "",
    "Udp": "30303",
    "Udp6": "",
    "Remainders": [
      {
        "key": "eth",
        "value": "c7c684dce96c2d80"
      },
      {
        "key": "snap",
        "value": "c0"
      }
    ],
    "IPAddressInfo": {
      "ip": "89.163.140.74",
      "registry": "RIPE",
      "registryStatus": "assigned",
      "registeredCountry": "DE",
      "registeredCountryName": "Germany",
      "organisation": "myLoc managed IT AG",
      "isReachableGlobally": true,
      "isBogon": false,
      "bgpPrefix": "89.163.128.0/17",
      "bgpPrefixNetworkAddress": "89.163.128.0",
      "bgpPrefixLastAddress": "89.163.255.255",
      "totalAddresses": 32768,
      "carriers": [
        {
          "asn": "AS24961",
          "asnNumeric": 24961,
          "organisation": "myLoc managed IT AG",
          "name": "MYLOC-AS",
          "registry": "Ripe",
          "registeredCountry": "DE",
          "registeredCountryName": "Germany",
          "registrationDate": "2002-06-10",
          "registrationLastChange": "2020-11-04",
          "totalIpv4Addresses": 132983,
          "totalIpv4Prefixes": 70,
          "totalIpv6Prefixes": 8,
          "rank": 1557,
          "rankText": "#1,557 out of 76,190"
        }
      ],
      "viaCarriers": [
        {
          "asn": "AS3356",
          "asnNumeric": 3356,
          "organisation": "Level 3 Parent, LLC",
          "name": "LEVEL3",
          "registry": "Arin",
          "registeredCountry": "US",
          "registeredCountryName": "United States of America (the)",
          "totalIpv4Addresses": 28207851,
          "rank": 14,
          "rankText": "#14 out of 76,190"
        },
        {
          "asn": "AS6939",
          "asnNumeric": 6939,
          "organisation": "Hurricane Electric LLC",
          "name": "HURRICANE",
          "registry": "Arin",
          "registeredCountry": "US",
          "registeredCountryName": "United States of America (the)",
          "totalIpv4Addresses": 442230,
          "rank": 660,
          "rankText": "#660 out of 76,190"
        },
        {
          "asn": "AS49544",
          "asnNumeric": 49544,
          "organisation": "i3D.net B.V",
          "name": "i3Dnet",
          "registry": "Ripe",
          "registeredCountry": "NL",
          "registeredCountryName": "Netherlands (the)",
          "totalIpv4Addresses": 99517,
          "rank": 1961,
          "rankText": "#1,961 out of 76,190"
        },
        {
          "asn": "AS36351",
          "asnNumeric": 36351,
          "organisation": "SoftLayer Technologies Inc.",
          "name": "SOFTLAYER",
          "registry": "Arin",
          "registeredCountry": "US",
          "registeredCountryName": "United States of America (the)",
          "totalIpv4Addresses": 4315451,
          "rank": 124,
          "rankText": "#124 out of 76,190"
        },
        {
          "asn": "AS6461",
          "asnNumeric": 6461,
          "organisation": "Zayo Bandwidth",
          "name": "ZAYO-6461",
          "registry": "Arin",
          "registeredCountry": "US",
          "registeredCountryName": "United States of America (the)",
          "totalIpv4Addresses": 1395944,
          "rank": 300,
          "rankText": "#300 out of 76,190"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```